# How do I create an event handler that can report progress from inside the method I am calling?

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, event-handling

I cannot find a simple example but I think this is possible. I am calling a single method. Inside that method it will loop many times and everyone time it iterates through the loop I want to inform the calling method and attach an event there so I can have a status bar to show progress.

So in other words I have a Winform with a status bar and in that WinForm app I call a method. Inside that method the loop iterates and I want to somehow get that information back to the WinForm app so I can change the status bar.

```
   if (fDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
       Session s = EncompassSession.Instance2(url, name, password);
       DataTable dt = ExcelHelper.ReadAsDataTable(fDialog.FileName.ToString());
       EncompassBoxHelper.UpdateBoxes(s, dt); //This is the main function that does the long process
       s.End();
   }
```

Comment: So what problems are you having doing that?  Pass a delegate to the method, have the type define an event, etc.   There are tons of ways of doing this.  What problems are you having with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of options, but one simple one would be to have your method take a special callback method as a parameter, and then invoke that method at certain points, providing context information.

```
public void UpdateBoxes(Session s, DataTable dt, Action<ProgressInfo> updateProgress)
{
    for (...)
    {
        ...
        updateProgress(new ProgressInfo(...));
    }
}
```

The method could then be called something like this:

```
   EncompassBoxHelper.UpdateBoxes(s, dt, 
       progress => UpdateProgressBar(progress));
```

Comment: thanks..trying this now.. its a whole new level of thinking for me